# Why is past tense not used?

Tags: grammar, tense

In my text book I saw the following conversation:

- A: I saw Brian a few days ago.
- B: Oh, did you? What's he doing these days?
- A: He's at university
- B: What's he studying?
- A: Psychology
- B: Is he enjoying it?
- A:Yes, he **says** it's a very good course.

Why is **says** used instead of **said**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [say](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/say) in two ways in this context. As it stands, **say** means to express an opinion. It's reasonable to assume that Brian still holds the same opinion, so you can use the present tense.

> Yes, he says it's a very good course.

You can also use **say** to simply report somebody's words. As Brian spoke in the past, you would use **said**. You can repeat what he said in two ways- with or without quotes. If you don't use quotes, it is reported speech and so you should consider [backshifting](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm) it (move it back a tense).

> He said "**It's** a very good course". - *quoted speech*
>   He said that **it was** a very good course. - *reported speech- backshifted*

For conversations, as this is, reported speech is much more widely than quoted speech. In this case, a backshift isn't essential, as it's still a good course, though most people would use and expect a backshift. This is what reported speech would look like without a backshift:

> He said that **it's** a very good course. - *reported speech- no backshift*

Comment: So can I say *John says he's really like pizza*? Because it's expressing an opinion what he still holds, that's right?

Comment: @Lai32290 Fixing the typo ("John says he really likes pizza"), yes, that sounds fine to my ears. ("John says he's really like pizza" makes sense if you wanted to mean that John claims that he is similar to pizza!)

Comment: For such recent speech, about a course Brian is still enrolled in, you can use "is a very good course" even for reported speech, and even with "said." It's still current information, and the course is still in progress. If you're having this conversation 6 months later, then past is more appropriate.

Comment: @Karen: I agree about  the backshift for **is** not being essential, and have updated my answer. As I have already stated, **says** indicates that Brian probably still holds that opinion, and has nothing to do with whether the course is still in progress. Note the present **says** in this sentence: "He says that his student days were the best years of his life". This is his current opinion, not reported speech- even if he told you several days ago.

Comment: This is also the basis of the joke "depends what the definition of 'is' is."

Comment: @fectin: That was no joke, that was a president defending himself against perjury charges. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_of_Bill_Clinton

Comment: And that specific line was a joke: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yp3TQf2xDc8

Answer (score 3):

There is a clear connection with the present. Even though the meeting itself occurred a few days ago, information is still relevant. At the moment of speaking Brain is still at university, he's studying psychology and enjoying it.

As for the last cue, the word *says* here is more about Brain's attitude towards the course than the mere fact he said something (as @JavaLatte mentioned in their answer). Likewise, at the moment of speaking he still thinks the course is good.

(*said* would sound formally correct, too, but so long as present tense is used before, *says* is more natural)

However if the meeting with Brain had happened a long time before the dialog, information might not be relevant anymore and past tense would make more sense. **Compare**:

> "I saw Brain a few years ago."
>
> "Oh, did you? What was he doing?"
>
> "He was at university"
>
> "What was he studying?"
>
> "Psychology"
>
> etc

Comment: As a native speaker: there's nothing formally wrong with _said_ here, but because the dialogue up to this point was all in the present - Brian _is_ at university, he _is_ studying psychology - it feels a little more natural to keep using the present until there's an active reason to need another tense.

Comment: @zwol, this answer's dialog about Brain – obviously a different person than Brian –  starts and remains in past tense.   The question's dialog actually starts out in past (“I saw Brian a few days ago”) but speaker B immediately shifts the discussion to present tense (“What's he doing these days?”), from which present-tense *says* follows naturally.